# How can I access the file system and sector of a hard disk drive by C++?

Tags: c++, windows, ntfs, fat32

How can I read a sector of a hard disk drive, access the file system and block or cluster of a file, list of bad blocks (FAT) or cluster file (NTFS)? Or access the list of free blocks (FAT) or cluster bitmap (NTFS)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CreateFile API to open a physical disk by specifying a special file name (e.g. `"\\.\PhysicalDrive0"`) -- see the section "Physical Disks and Volumes" in the [CreateFile MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Be very careful though, especially with write operations -- you can easily trash your entire system this way.

Answer (score 0):

Examining FAT boot sector: *[Extract Floppy Disk Geometry from the Boot Sector](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/files/article.php/c13809/)*

*[FAT Root Directory Structure on Floppy Disk and File Information](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/files/article.php/c13831/)*

*[Long File Name (LFN) Entries in the FAT Root Directory of Floppy Disks](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/files/article.php/c13907/)* in win32.