# C# Keep a program running in the background till the computer completely shuts down

Tags: c#, shutdown

Basically, I am making a program that blocks the internet access after 11h PM. But my only problem is that there is many ways to bypass it, such as shutting down the computer and the user just have to wait until the process gets closed by the OS itself then cancel the shutdown operation (Windows 7).

Any ways to make sure that the program won't get terminated before the pc shutdowns or anything?

Comment: Why not just invest in a cheap router that allows you configure access schedules?

Comment: Just a guess, but shouldn't that be possible with a Service?

Comment: @dowhilefor, a service can be stopped

Comment: @Erno if you have the rights to do so. Obviously if the user has full admin rights, he can do whatever he wants. If it is a restricted user a service should work fine.

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz your question was about the internet access, so of course you can still play games without internet. Do you want to stop the whole user account from working after 11pm? How about [Parental Controls](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Set-up-Parental-Controls)?

Comment: Rather than asking how to make an unkillable process (which is the makings of a virus) you will likely get more helpful (and less potentially malicious) responses if you simply ask about how to use parental controls to limit your child's internet access.  It's better for everyone if we help you solve your underlying problem, not tell you how to use some mechanism that you thing will solve your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to block internet access, I recommend enforcing this rule on your router rather than on your PCs.  It would be a much simpler, much more reliable solution.  Your router probably already supports the feature, but if it doesn't you can buy a new consumer-grade router (dirt-cheap) and/or install a custom firmware that does (see [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/firmware) Firmware for the Linksys WRT-54GL and company).

If the router approach just won't work for you, and you must block internet access in software, I would first suggest investigating Windows "local policy" or "group policy" to see if they can do what you want.

If that's too complex for your taste, try finding an off-the-shelf solution.  Look into ZoneAlarm or NetNanny to see if one of them will do the trick.

But if you are bent on writing a C# program to do it for you, you probably want to look into [writing a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Services are more complex to write and deploy, but they can be configured to run at boot and are not slaved to a user session like regular desktop apps.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually somewhat complex. It's like a virus - how do you keep it running, always?

You might want to read about drivers. Drivers have the highest "trust" by the operating system. They can physically access anything in the computer. Anything but a driver or a core file may be closed by the user manually, is some way or another.
Another thing you can do is to "burn" the file into `Kernal.DLL` or such. You can do it with a different operating system on the computer (e.g Linux) or by physically writing to the hard disk (not via Windows's API). To physically access the driver, [check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223246/how-can-i-access-the-file-sytem-and-sector-of-harddisk-by-c)